# plotting in matlab two sets of data with different lenghts

Tags: plot, range, line, axis

This is a bit embarrasing, but an external HDD I was using for my research recently died, and now it's taking me ages to remember what did I do to create some graphs, for which the code I've been cutting and pasting for quite a lot. 
My issue is quite silly: I have different sets of x-values for each of the variables and one of them starts at a different moment for the same x-axis. When I try to plot them together defining the same X-axis I get an error. I tried `plot` and `line` and looked for options but with no luck.

Any help is much appreciated

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not sure this is the best way to deal with this, but at least it's a workaround that helped me deal with the problem.

I have two sets of data (with different y-scales, but that's not the issue here), one with yearly values of x from 950 to 1850 AD, and the other with values every 10 years from 850 to 1850, so they have the same x-axis but one of them has a "delay" over the other.

What I did is creating an array of NaNs:

`Nans=zeros([100 1],'single').*NaN;`

and then concatenate it to my first variable:

`Varc=cat(1,Nans,Var);`

I defined the x of the first variable as `yrA=(850:1850)';` and the x of the second variable as `yrB=(850:10:1850)';`. With that changes I could finally plot them together. I hope this helps, although it seems a bit weird way to deal with the problem, so I'm sure there's a more elegant approach ;-)

All the best